# How to replicate changes to a folder to its mirror/image?

Tags: windows, backup, sync

Say I have a folder with multiple files and subfolders and several backups of this folder.

Now I am planning to make many changes to the way this folder is organized: changing file locations, naming and repositioning subfolders.

How can I save the changes I do so that I can replicate them on the many different backups I have of this folder.

Copying the folder is not an option.

Comment: The question is very broad. Almost any backup/copy command can do this. Xcopy, Robocopy, RSync and any other backup-program.

Comment: Agree, [Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx)